# How to convert in R a list of values (x,y,value) to a 2D matrix

Tags: r, data-manipulation

On input I have a list of rows such as:

```
a a 1
a b 2
a c 3
b a 4
b b 5
b c 6
c a 7
c b 8
c c 9
```

I need to read the list in R and work with a matrix or data frame

```
    a b c
  +-------
a | 1 2 3
b | 4 5 6
b | 7 8 9
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently for large matrices with 50k rows and columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `reshape2::acast()`:

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df, V1 ~ V2, value.var = "V3")
  a b c
a 1 2 3
b 4 5 6
c 7 8 9
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
"c"), V2 = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), V3 = 1:9), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option is `xtabs`

```
xtabs(V3 ~ ., df)
#   V2
#V1  a b c
#  a 1 2 3
#  b 4 5 6
#  c 7 8 9
```